# Set up two IPs (one using DHCP and other static) over the same Interface

Tags: linux, networking

I am trying to set up 2 IPs using just one interface. I need this because if the DHCP server is not available the device must be accessible through a static IP. After reading many posts here (and in other forums) and doing many test my /etc/network/interfaces is as follows:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s3
allow-hotplug enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp

auto enp0s3:0
allow-hotplug enp0s3:0
iface enp0s3:0 inet static
address 192.168.254.250
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

This seems to work but the static IP is not accessible until the DHCP IP is configured, and I need to access the device through the static IP if there no DHCP server running in the network.
It is important to bear in mind that in the best case I should be able to access the device using either the IP got from DHCP and the static one.

Any advice will be really welcome.

Comment: The first though that I had was, "Use a VM to create the second IP" but I do not think that is a good answer.

Comment: Can you try switching the DHCP and static address so that the DHCP one is `:0` and the `ensp0s3` is the static?
Here is a handy link: https://www.garron.me/en/linux/add-secondary-ip-linux.html

If that fixes it, I will write up an answer for you.

Comment: Why do you need to have the hotplug lines?

Comment: The hotplug is because I don't know if the interface will be a hot plugged one, so I thought it will be more secure to include the line. Is it any drawback of using it? And I need the DHCP to be primary interface because it has been specified that the used by default will be the DHCP one, being the static just for maintenance purposes.

Comment: When you say hot plugged,are you referring to the interface card, cable or the hot plug API of network manager? I have a theory that the hotplug option is messing with it. This might help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/547289/how-can-i-from-cli-assign-multiple-ip-addresses-to-one-interface

Comment: Actually, change the interface index to `enp0s3:1` instead of `enp0s3:0` I believe that `:0` is referring to the base address of the adaptor.

Comment: Mainly, it will be an Ethernet cable what could be hotplugged. I am going to read the link you pasted. I tried also to put :1 instead of :0 but I got the same result. I think I am having an issue with the VM (right now I am using a VM), because the VM seems to need the cable connected even to PING between the HOST and the GUEST.

Comment: If it is just an ethernet cable then you you do not need the hot plug option, the hot plug option (from my research) is for the network manager API. Network manager will automatically handle the hot plugging of the cable without the need for specifying `allow-hotplug`

Comment: I will remove the allow-hotplug then. Thanks!!

Comment: Any luck after removal?

Comment: It seems to be working :). Thanks!! Now I am going to test it running on the final HW and I am going to open another POST related to the predictable interface naming :_). Thanks again

Comment: No problem I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Based upon testing various settings, it appears that your `allow-hotplug` is your culprit.

Based upon the explanation given by another user at the unix site (see link below), you really do not need it unless you are hooking into the network system with your application via the `hotplug` event.

---

### Add another ip address to an adaptor

In your `/etc/network/interfaces` file create your standard interface definition.

After it is created then add a secondary configuration in this manner:

#### Template:

```
auto [iface]:[n]
iface [iface]:[n] inet static
standard attributes here...
```

Whenever you specify the interface name, ensure you also specify the index number of the new virtual interface (the secondary ip address).
`n` is the interface index.

#### Example:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp

auto enp0s3:1
iface enp0s3:1 inet static
address 192.168.254.250
netmask 255.255.255.0

auto enp0s3:2
iface enp0s3:2 inet static
address 10.0.0.2
netmask 255.255.0.0
gateway 10.0.0.1
```

In the above example we have the loopback adaptor created normally and the standard dhcp configuration for the normal interface.

Then we create two additional interfaces, both are statically configured, one on the `192.168.254.0` network and the other on the `10.0.0.0` network.
The second virtual interface has the gateway configured while the first does not.

---

### Tl;Dr

Remove the `allow-hotplug` lines from your network config.

---

### Links

What is `allow-hotplug`?
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192671/what-is-a-hotplug-event-from-the-interface

How to have more than one ip address on a single interface:
https://www.garron.me/en/linux/add-secondary-ip-linux.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have Ubuntu, and therefore probably also Netplan (a replacement for `if-up-down` that you're using now). I'll let you research Netplan on your own, and how Cloud-init may also be there in the mix, but just to show you a simple Netplan config I use to do the same:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
      addresses:
        - 11.22.33.44/24
```

The main difference with your solution is that it doesn't need an alias interface. For various reasons, they are annoying. This also means that `ifconfig` won't show both the addresses, but `ifconfig` is (somewhat) deprecated, and you should use `ip -4 addr` instead.

The above config will make 11.22.33.44 the primary address, and the DHCP address will show up as `secondary` in `ip -4 addr`